Parse Nested JSON payload using pyspark
I am trying to parse, flatten the nested data using pyspark. any suggestion on how to parse such json file
Here is sample code tried so far, but was not successful.
jsonData ="""{
    "data": {
        "unique_id1": {
            "random_code1": {
                "name": "some_name",
                "status": "value1"
            },
            "random_code2": {
                "name": "some_name",
                "status": "value2"
            }
        },
        "unique_id2": {
            "random_code3": {
                "name": "some_name",
                "status": "value2"
            },
            "random_code4": {
                "name": "some_name",
                "status": "value2"
            }
        }
    }

}"""
df = spark.read.option("multiLine", "true").json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([jsonData]))

data_schema = df.schema["data"].dataType.simpleString()
data_schema  = re.sub(r"([\w\-]+)(?=:struct<name)", "_RandomCode", data_schema)
data_schema  = re.sub(r"([\w\-]+)(?=:struct<_RandomCode)", "_Ids", data_schema)
data_schema = re.sub(r"(?<=,|<)([^,<]+)(?=:)", r"`\1`", data_schema)

Expected output
_Ids              _RandomCode              name
unique_id1         random_code1            some_name
unique_id1         random_code2            some_name

unique_id2         random_code3            some_name
unique_id2         random_code4            some_name


You can parse the data by using map and then convert it back to the desired format and extract the relevant columns from the data.
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode_outer

jsonData ="""{
    "data": {
        "unique_id1": {
            "random_code1": {
                "name": "some_name",
                "status": "value1"
            },
            "random_code2": {
                "name": "some_name",
                "status": "value2"
            }
        },
        "unique_id2": {
            "random_code3": {
                "name": "some_name",
                "status": "value2"
            },
            "random_code4": {
                "name": "some_name",
                "status": "value2"
            }
        }
    }

}"""
df = spark.read.option("multiLine", "true").json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([jsonData]))

def parse_data(x):

    # Top level keys:
    out = []
    outer_list = [(key, x[0].asDict()[key].asDict()) for key in x[0].asDict().keys()]

    for row in outer_list :
        for sub_row in [(key, row[1][key]['name']) for key in row[1].keys()]:
            out.append([row[0], sub_row[0], sub_row[1]])
    
    return out

# Convert to RDD and parse the data, convert the RDD
# back to a dataframe and explode.
df = df.rdd.map(lambda x: (1, parse_data(x))).toDF(['dummy', 'parsed_data'])
df = df.withColumn('parsed_data', explode_outer(df['parsed_data']))

# Fetch desired columns from the parsed data.
df = (df.withColumn('_Ids', df['parsed_data'].getItem(0))
        .withColumn('_RandomCode', df['parsed_data'].getItem(1))
        .withColumn('name', df['parsed_data'].getItem(2))
        .drop('dummy', 'parsed_data'))

df.show()

+----------+------------+---------+
|      _Ids| _RandomCode|     name|
+----------+------------+---------+
|unique_id1|random_code1|some_name|
|unique_id1|random_code2|some_name|
|unique_id2|random_code3|some_name|
|unique_id2|random_code4|some_name|
+----------+------------+---------+


